# Where in JHipster generated project is specified front-end source folder for production profile?

Tags: angularjs, gradle, spring-boot, jhipster

When i run project with production profile, source code for front-end part is loaded from webapp subfolder called 'dist'. My question is: Where is configured this setting in spring , gradle, grunt ? I've studied project for a while but can't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find it in the Spring configuration. [StaticResourcesProductionFilter.java](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/app/templates/src/main/java/package/web/filter/_StaticResourcesProductionFilter.java)
and [WebConfigurer.java](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/app/templates/src/main/java/package/config/_WebConfigurer.java)